# Facebook buttons not expanding container div

Tags: facebook, html, facebook-like, expand

I am having a problem getting a div containing facebook like/send buttons to expand when the buttons are clicked.  I have searched and tried and tried to fix this, but I'm hitting a wall.  I believe it has something to do with how the buttons render an iframe, but I'm not sure.

Here's the code, plain and simple (with an example link for og data).

```
<div id="fb_btns">
<fb:like href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" data-send="true" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="false" ></fb:like>
</div>
```

and the non-expanding div can be seen here

http://spadeballink.com/GALLOWS/TheGoddamnGallows.html

Any help counts!  Thanks in advance!

*Also there is no css declaring the height of this div, the only heights declared are for html and body to be 100% (needed for the background image).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using XFBML or Iframe version of like button? For Iframe version you need to use layout=standard for people to be able to see fly-out comment box.

Comment: Thanks. XFBML. I'm getting the comment box to fly-out fine, however the div containing the like and send buttons doesn't expand to the fly-out comment box.

Comment: I checked your link now, it seems to be working fine. Is the issue resolved?.